# How to get the statistics of LoL which is not shown in the official site

Tags: league-of-legends

I saw this on [LoLwiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20130421094901/http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lux/Ability_Details)
[image]
<sub>(source: [qpic.cn](http://t2.qpic.cn/mblogpic/d5e5600bd489bb579a7c/2000))</sub>

I noticed the projectile speed here is not shown in the official LoL site.

How to get the statistics like this? By hacking or do some test in a LoL game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Some are [given](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=17785242#17785242) by developers on the [forums](http://clgaming.net/redtracker/36937-projectile-speeds).
- Some are [mentioned (see galio)](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1016900) in patch notes.
- Some are [pulled](http://www.reignofgaming.net/news/24320-updated-pbe-aatrox-the-darkin-blade-is-back-woad) straight from the data files.
- Some are [calculated](http://www.leaguebot.net/forum/Upload/showthread.php?tid=2070) using their observed movement in game.

Note that projectile speed uses the same unit type as movement speed.

Comment: Wow, you must be an expert in LoL

Comment: @Sayakiss Or master googler ;)